# Como puedo iterar este map?

Tags: c++

Digamos que quiero poder eliminar y añadir una Bicicleta del stock que sigue la siguiente estructura:

```
map<string, priority_queue<Bicicleta*, vector<Bicicleta*>, CmpBicicleta>> stockTienda;
```

Donde el string seria el modelo de la bicicleta. Y yo quiero eliminar la bicicleta más antigua de ese modelo.

La funcion CmpBicicleta es:

```
struct CmpBicicleta {
    bool operator()(Bicicleta* a, Bicicleta* b) const
    {
        return b->getDataEntrada() < a->getDataEntrada();
    }
};
```

Comment: ¿Tienes un ejemplo de los datos de entrada y la salida que esperas?

Answer (score 0):

No tienes que iterar nada para las operaciones que mencionas. Si conoces el modelo, empieza por buscarlo:

```
auto encontrado = stockTienda.find(modelo); // modelo es un std::string

if (encontrado != stockTienda.end())
{
    // Entramos aquí si el modelo existe.
}
```

Una vez tienes el iterador que apunta al modelo, puedes insertar así:

```
encontrado->second.push(new Bicicleta{/* parámetros de construcción */});
//          ^^^^^^ <--- first es el modelo, second es la priority_queue
```

Y puedes eliminar así:

```
encontrado->second.pop();
//          ^^^^^^ <--- first es el modelo, second es la priority_queue
```

Answer (score 0):

La priority queue ya es una estructura que siempre mantiene el elemento principal en el top basándose en tu función de ordenamiento. Dado que no explicas lo que regresa "getDataEntrada()", supondré que tu función de ordenamiento siempre deja en el top a la bicicleta mas antigua.

Con ello solo bastará hacer

```cpp
stockTienda["modelo"].pop();
```

para que elimines el modelo más antiguo.  Y para insertar una nueva solo deberás hacer

```cpp
stockTienda["modelo"].insert(bicicletaYaConstruida);
```

Al final lo importante es que tu función de ordenamiento mantenga en el top la más antigua, o de lo contrario no funcionará.